# What are the differences and similarties between Scala traits vs. Java 8 interfaces?

Tags: java, scala

I am new to Scala started learning the language for fun and I am still trying to get my head around it. My understanding of Scala traits is that they are like java interfaces except that some methods can have an implementation.

Java 8 is adding interfaces that can have default methods where an implementation can be provided.

What are the similarities and differences between Java 8 interfaces and Scala traits?

Comment: check out that website, it might help you http://www.infoq.com/articles/java-8-vs-scala

Comment: tl;dr: **The primary motivator for virtual extension methods [default methods] is API evolution. A welcome side effect is that they offer a form of multiple inheritance, which is limited to behaviour. Traits in Scala not only provide multiple inheritance of behaviour, but also of state. Besides state and behaviour inheritance, traits offer a means to get a reference to the implementing class... [Scala] traits offer a richer set of features than [Java 8's] virtual extension methods.**

Comment: Have you thought about sealing one of the traits under the other?

Answer (score 49):

Motivations for **Java 8' default methods** and **Scala traits** differ.

The former was introduced to support safe API evolution and a limited form of multiple inheritance. With leveraging functional programming idioms in Project Lambda it's been beneficial to add, for example, a *`forEach(lambda)`* method to `java.util.Collection` interface without altering all possible implementers (which is actually impossible to do without breaking backward compatibility). As a side effect this also offered a form of [mixin composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixin).

*Scala traits* were designed from scratch as building blocks for modular components composition. They are multiple inheritance friendly and don't have [diamond problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance) by having strict rules on evaluation order of mix-ins due to linearization. They also support state, can reference the implementing class and place restrictions on which type can mix-in them. Look at Scala collections library where traits are used thoroughly.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on this "Scala traits were designed from scratch as building blocks for modular components composition." ?

Answer (score 15):

Note that with [scala 2.12.0 RC1 (Sept. 2016)](http://scala-lang.org/news/2.12.0-RC1), `Trait` now compiles to an interface.
Scala 2.12 is all about making optimal use of Java 8’s new features

> With Java 8 allowing concrete methods in interfaces, Scala 2.12 is able to compile a trait to a single interface.
>
> **Before, a trait was represented as a class that held the method implementations and an interface**.
> Note that the compiler still has quite a bit of magic to perform behind the scenes, so that care must be taken if a trait is meant to be implemented in Java.
> (Briefly, if a trait does any of the following its subclasses require synthetic code: defining fields, calling super, initializer statements in the body, extending a class, relying on linearization to find implementations in the right super trait.)

See [scala PR 5003](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/5003) more the difference of implementation.

Answer (score 7):

On similarity, both can have default methods,

Differences side, We can add traits to only instance, and not to entire class as well. Example:

```
trait A { def m = ??? }
class B 

new B() with A
```

Like wise we can keep adding trait layers on an instance.